# SQL query when joining two tables

Tags: sql

I need to join two tables in SQL and I need to find the counts of how many customer id's in table A are also found in table B, extracting how many Customer id in A's also purchased in table B by year.  My query is as follows:

```
SELECT
  a.year, count(distinct(a.id), 
  count (distinct(b.id)
FROM
  purchase as A, 
  purchase2 as B
WHERE 
  (a.id=b.id) 
  AND 
  a.year>2010
GROUP BY a.year
```

Is this correct? do I need to include count(distinct(b.id) in the select statement? do I also need to group by b.year?

thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. Enclosing the column after the `distinct` keyword in parentheses won't change anything `distinct (a)` is the same as `distinct a`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Change your distinct, and you can do an inner join to be sure :

```
SELECT
  A.year, 
  count(DISTINCT A.id), 
  count (DISTINCT B.id)
FROM
  purchase as A 
  INNER JOIN purchase2 B ON B.id = A.id
WHERE 
  A.year>2010
GROUP BY 
  A.year,
  B.year
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response, when I  query this way, I don't get totals by year, not sure what it's doing but for instance 2017 shows 31 counts when I defined a.year=2017

Answer (score 0):

I think `union all` and aggregation is the best approach.  Start with the information *per* id/year:

```
select id, year, max(in_a), max(in_b)
from ((select distinct id, year, 1 as in_a, 0 as in_b
       from purchase
      ) union all
      (select distinct id, year, 0 as in_a, 1 as in_b
       from purchase2
      ) 
     ) ab
group by id, year;
```

Then aggregate this by year:

```
select year,
       sum(in_a) as total_a,
       sum(in_b) as total_b,
      sum(in_a * in_b) as in_both
from (select id, year, max(in_a), max(in_b)
      from ((select distinct id, year, 1 as in_a, 0 as in_b
             from purchase
            ) union all
            (select distinct id, year, 0 as in_a, 1 as in_b
             from purchase2
            ) 
           ) ab
      group by id, year
     ) iy
group by year;
```